# How to delete the outliers

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, outliers

I manage to apply the interquartile range principle well but when I display the mustache box of the dataset without outliers, I see that there are always outliers. what is wrong?
Here is code :

```
# Load libraries
import pandas as pd;
from pandas import read_csv, set_option;
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt;

# Load dataset
filename         = "/home/fogang/dataset/Regression/Housing Boston/housing.csv";
df               = read_csv(filename, header=0);
df = df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1);  # Let's delete the column 'Unnamed: 0'
one_dim         = pd.DataFrame();
one_dim['rm']    = df['rm'];

#shape dataset
print(one_dim.shape);

# Peek at dataset
print(one_dim.head(10));

# Let's look whether there are NaN values
print(one_dim.isnull().sum());

# Box and whisker plots
one_dim.plot(kind='box', subplots=True, layout=(1, 1), sharex=False, sharey=False, fontsize=12);
plt.show();

# Describe Dataset
print(one_dim.describe());

# Let's find Inter-Quartile Range
unidim        = one_dim['rm'];
unidim_Q1     = unidim.quantile(0.25);
unidim_Q3     = unidim.quantile(0.75);
unidim_IQR    = unidim_Q3 - unidim_Q1;
unidim_lower  = unidim_Q1 - (1.5 * unidim_IQR);
unidim_upper  = unidim_Q3 + (1.5 * unidim_IQR);

# Outliers
unidim_outliers  = pd.DataFrame();
unidim_outliers['outliers'] = unidim[(unidim < unidim_lower) | (unidim > unidim_upper)]
unidim_outliers.info()

# Good data
unidim_good  = pd.DataFrame();
unidim_good['good'] = unidim[(unidim >= unidim_lower) & (unidim <= unidim_upper)];
unidim_good.info();

unidim_good.plot(kind='box', subplots=True, layout=(1, 2), sharex=False, sharey=False, fontsize=12);
plt.show();
```

What to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too wide spread outliers from both tails - up and down. So, then you cut out some of outliers and check it again, you have new outliers in cutted data.
If you want totally get rid of outliers with one cut you can do it using more strict rule to cut, for example by so:

```
unidim_lower  = unidim_Q1 - (1.3 * unidim_IQR);
unidim_upper  = unidim_Q3 + (1.3 * unidim_IQR);
```

But I should warn you: not all 'outliers' are bad for the model, you shoud choose wisely what to treat as 'ouliers' and what is usefull data anyway.

Comment: Ok thanks. I try it later, it's christmas today. Yes i already had to read that all the outliers are not always bad for the model. How to know, what are the criteria which make it possible to know that an outlier is good for moodel?

Comment: You should use cross validation and hold out part of data to check you score. Simply try your model with and without outliers and look at model score in each case. Sometime is useful to have several different models (first without outliers and second especially to detect and treat outliers) and somehow combine results in the end of your pipeline.